# System.Timers.Timer stops by itself in a windows service

Tags: timer, windows-services, .net-4.0

Hello I'm doing a check on a windows service that seems to stop doing its work after a undeterminate amount of time. The service keeps running but method OnElapsedTime stops getting executed, i know because the logs simply stop getting written.

I suspect that the timer stops (maybe GC collected?)

This is the basic code for my Windows Service

```
public class WindowsServiceWorker : ServiceBase
{
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new Timer();//timer used to cycle execution

        public WIndowsServiceWorker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();//default method for windows service designer
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //log service start
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 30000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
        }

        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //log onElapsed started execution
                //do work calling entity framework and send emails
                //log onElapsed done
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log exception
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
               //write log service stop 
        }
```

I cannot reproduce the problem, logs after some days at random simply stop and users open tickets that emails are not sent.

Event viewer do not report anything abnormal, the only way to restore the execution cycles is restarting the service.

Could the problem be caused because the variable `System.Timers.Timer timer` is not declared static?